# Quick start programming on Netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, netbeans-platform

I am learning how to develop a desktop application based on **Netbeans Platform Application**, so I have started with the famous [Quick start tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html), I have been blocked to understand that piece of code (Netbeans 8.0 platform developers can get it):

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       String enteredText = text.getText();
        Collection<? extends WordFilter> allFilters = Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(WordFilter.class);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (WordFilter textFilter : allFilters) {
            String processedText = textFilter.process(enteredText);
            sb.append(processedText).append("\n");
        }
        text.setText(sb.toString());
    }
```

What I did not understand and of course it is the reason of an execution problem with my code is the line:
*Collection allFilters = Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(WordFilter.class);*

Can anyone explain it to me, what `lookup` is? and what that way of using `Collection` is? (there is no explanation in the tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for [Lookup class](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util-lookup/org/openide/util/Lookup.html). Please take a look.

The Collection construction means a collection of objects who's classes extend the WordFilter class (or implements the WordFilter interface, in case WordFilter is an interface).

Answer (score 1):

Toni Epple wrote an approachable explanation of the Netbeans Lookup here:

[Netbeans Lookups Explained!](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/netbeans-lookups-explained)

The community wiki also has a good introduction to the Lookup concept and API:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/AboutLookup

And so does the Netbeans Developer FAQ:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqLookup

These all provide explanations, code samples, and links to further resources. They're very useful in comprehending the Lookup API documentation itself.